# Issue with Conga Subquery not returning the correct value in a detail table

Tags: query, form, merge, merge-field, conga

I'm having an issue with where a value from a subquery in a conga query is not returning the correct value in a detail table. I tested the conga query in Salesforce query editor and its working correctly there. The issue is probably with my conga template. Everything in the template is populating correctly except for the Competitors cells. It fills in the same value over and over again for each row of the table.

`SELECT Id, Name (SELECT Id, Name, Product__c, Product__r.Simplified_Product__c, Projected_Members__c, Opportunity_Name__c FROM Opportunity_Products__r ), (SELECT Id FROM Competitor_Relationships__r) FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = '{pv0}' AND IsClosed = FALSE`

[image: Conga Word Template]

Answer (score 0):

So the table structure that you're using is not properly configured to support nested data  You'll likely need to insert "Nested Tables" for each of the subquery regions.  See the image below.  Of course you can format the borders so that everything looks like a single consistent table but the nested table will be required for you to achieve your desired results

[image]